# The abelian group of smallest order and smallest non prime integer n divides |G| but G doesn't have an element of order n?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I don't know how to think of an example. What's an example of such a group. It doesn't make sense to me because if it is a finite abelian group, it can be written as a direct product of the integers mod (a prime number). And shouldn't it always have an element of that order if it divides it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.  It has order $4$ but all elements have order one or two.

Comment: The identity has order one.

Comment: @Nishant Good catch, I fixed it

Comment: Looks good to me. It's always elements with 2 that do the most unique things.

Comment: @user121615 True, though you could play the same trick with any $n$, the group $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ has order $2n$ but all elements have order dividing $n$.

Comment: Actually the group has order $n^2$ not $2n$. (Still it can serve as example.)

Comment: @quid Ack, I was sloppy again, thanks for the correction.  Fortunately the point of the example stands.